# How to keep both checkbox and text in the same line

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am having problem keeping checkbox and text in the same line.

This is the HTML code:

```
<span class="list-item">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" value="Some payment">&nbsp;Some payment
  </label>
</span>
```

How can I make this work. The only display attribute on  element that gives the desired effect is display: `display: -webkit-box;` that only works in Chrome.

Any help much appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Its already on same line. http://dabblet.com/gist/7428994 Make a fiddle or snapshot to show the difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This HTML renders in the way you want:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MmxVUajiMiL8s3OlfvHf?p=preview)

```
<span class="list-item">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" value="Some payment">&nbsp;Some payment
  </label>
</span>
```

Are you maybe applying some other styling to it?

Comment: true ... there was a display:block defined on input (general). I havent separated checkbox input from that :/